# Is there a JQuery plugin for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, plugins

I want to display a list of names (with description underneath).  Preferably scrollable if the list of names is too big.

Then, I want the user to click and select one of them.

Perhaps if the person made a mistake, I want them to reselect?

Comment: i don't recall SO being turned into a "do my work for me for free" kind of place? :)

Comment: I haved tried this and this and I can't figure this out. Here is what I have done so far: "...." usually. Also a little vague on what exactly you are after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) is [capable of functionality like this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data); not sure if you need users to type into an input to search though.  I think each of your requirements are exhibited in the demos.